# Where to put standalone-django scripts without breaking imports?

Tags: python, django

I'm still pretty new to Python.

I have a Django website with several apps and a `/libs` directory. I need to add a couple cron jobs that will use my Django models. I've already worked all that out, no big deal.

I have a problem with my imports, though.

I would like to include these scripts in the App they generally belong-to. But when I execute the script from the commandline, it's unable to load modules from the `/libs` directory.

To illustrate specifically the dir structure, imagine this pseudo-code:

```
import ./../libs/mysharedlib.py
```

In other words the scripts and sharedlib are:

```
~/project/myapp/myscript.py

~/project/libs/mysharedlib.py
```

I get that I could just add `~/project` to my `PYTHONPATH` but then I have to worry about doing this during deployment and it just feels broken.

Should I move my scripts out of my apps and put them in the `~/project`? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a better way, custom management commands solve this.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

These let you write stand alone utility scripts.  You can run these as a cron or just as utilities.  They use the exact same paths as any other module in your django app.

While these solve import problems does your libs directory have a `__init__.py` file? Can you import your lib directory in your views? Or is your import just not working in your cron scripts?  Either way custom managment commands address this.

Comment: I haven't tried using any libs outside of these scripts yet. Still building things out. But yes, it does have an __init__.py. And I'm assuming that when running in wsgi the project directory will be in the import path?